# How to set extra_vars while running ansilbe-playbook programmatically in python3.5?(Ansible version - 2.8)

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, python-3.5, ansible-2.x

```
import os
import json
from collections import namedtuple
from ansible import context
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.utils.vars import load_extra_vars
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor

def execute_ansible_playbook(CLOUD_TO_USE=None, PLAYBOOK=None):
    playbook_path = PLAYBOOK
    #inventory_path = "hosts"

    #Options = namedtuple('Options', ['connection', 'module_path', 'forks', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'check', 'diff', 'listhosts', 'listtasks', 'listtags', 'syntax'])
    loader = DataLoader()
    passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')

    inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='inventory/' + CLOUD_TO_USE)
    #inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='localhost')
    variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
    executor = PlaybookExecutor(  
                playbooks=[playbook_path], 
                inventory=inventory, 
                variable_manager=variable_manager, 
                loader=loader,  
                passwords=passwords
            )  
    results = executor.run()  
    print (results)
```

I got this code from [Run Ansible playbook programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533577/run-ansible-playbook-programmatically)

This is running properly for other ansible-playbooks. But now I want to pass extra_vars to an ansible-playbook. I couldn't find a proper answer.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW. Use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The [documentation](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#usage-examples) is not complete. All parameters are described in the [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/blob/master/ansible_runner/interface.py).